# How do I dynamically show more bootstrap tabs in a _Layout template?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an existing site using MVC and a _Layout page using a sectional control for the render.  We are using bootstrap tabs throughout for data displays.

I have simplified this setup, but there are other VMs binding to this page, so I can't bind to the whole page, which would be the easy route for what I need.

I want to have a dynamic amount of tabs being rendered like:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="tabContentParent" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="result">
            <!-- various details of a report -->
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: myVM -->
        <div class="tab-pane" data-bind="attr: {'id': reportId}">
            <!-- various bindings for reports -->
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Areas/Results/VMs/myVM.js")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.myVM.load();
        ko.applyBindings(app.myVM, document.getElementById('tabContentParent'));
    </script>
}
```

How can I get the tabs to also reproduce like this when they are in a separate sectional control and not within the same data-binding area?

```
@section controls
{
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs section-controls">
        <li class="active"><a href="#result" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
        <li class="hidden" id="tab1"><a href="#report1" data-toggle="tab">Report 1</a></li>
        <li class="hidden" id="tab2"><a href="#report2" data-toggle="tab">Report 1</a></li>
        <!-- etc., etc. -->
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, or if this is the best way to use knockout... but I think I have figured out how to do this.  I have bound the `ViewModel` to multiple sections in separate `applyBindings` calls.  I haven't seen this as a solution or suggestion before so I am not sure if there are side-effects.

A fiddle: [Knockout multi-binding](https://jsfiddle.net/gregmason/1esmsxL8/3/) showing the functioning solution I propose.  I defined the nav tabs like so:

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs section-controls" id="vm1Id2">
    <li class="active"><a href="#result" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
    <!-- ko foreach: tabInfos -->
    <li>
      <a data-bind="text: text, attr:{ href: '#' + url }" data-toggle="tab"></a>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

I defined the tab context like so (and a vm/div as a separator):

```
<div id="vm2Id">
  <p>
    <label data-bind="text: message"></label>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div id="vm1Id1" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="result">
      <label>Some data displayed here</label>
    </div>
    <!-- ko foreach: newTabs -->
    <div class="tab-pane" data-bind="attr: {'id': $data}">
      <label data-bind="text: $data"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally, I bound everything a little double time.

```
var ViewModel1 = function() {
  var newTabs = ko.observableArray(["report1", "report2"]);
  var tabInfos = ko.observableArray([{text: "Report 1", url: "report1"}, {text: "Report 2", url: "report2"}]);
  return {
    newTabs: newTabs,
    tabInfos: tabInfos
  };
};

var ViewModel2 = function() {
  var message = ko.observable("This is a message as a space holder");
  return {
    message: message
  };
};

var vm1 = new ViewModel1();
var vm2 = new ViewModel2();
ko.applyBindings(vm1, document.getElementById('vm1Id1'));
ko.applyBindings(vm1, document.getElementById('vm1Id2'));
ko.applyBindings(vm2, document.getElementById('vm2Id'));
```

I **think** this is the correct way to approach this.  It works well enough when the page renders.